# How to ceil decimal places in float?

Tags: javascript

What I need is this behaviour:

Input: `2.11`, `2.12`, `2.13`, `2.14`, `2.15`, `2.16`

Output for all cases: `2.2`

JavaScipt native [toFixed(1)](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) gives `2.2` only if input is greater then `2.15`

Please pardon me if this is duplicate. But I didn't find such question.

Please tell me if the title of the question is misleading and I should rename it.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: number times 10, ceil, then divide the result by 10.

Comment: See the duplicate question and replace `Math.round` with `Math.ceil`.